# Retain the value selected in dynamic DropDown list (dependent on another DD list) on page-load (Edit) event

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

**Following is the HTML code for two Dropdown lists. Second one get populated based on the value selected in the first one.**

```
<label>
<span>Mode:</span>
<select id='car' onchange='configureDropDownLists()'>
<option value=''>Choose the Mode of Transport</option>
<option value='Car'>Car</option>
<option value='Plane'>Plane</option>
</select>
</label><br/>

<label>
<span>Choose the preferred company</span>
<select id='company' onchange='getMessage()'>
<option value=''>Choose the Company</option>
</select>
</label><br/>

<p id='message' style='display:'></p>
```

**JavaScript code to populate the second DropDown list:**

```
function configureDropDownLists()
{
var carComp = ['Porsche', 'BMW', 'Merc', 'Audi', 'Hummer'];
var planeComp = ['Boeing', 'BAC', 'BAE', 'GE'];
var ModeVar=document.getElementById('car').value;
switch (ModeVar);
{
case 'Car':
    company.options.length = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < carComp.length; i++)
    {
        createOption(company, carComp[i], carComp[i]);
    }
    break;
case 'Plane':
    company.options.length = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < planeComp.length; i++)
    {
        createOption(company, planeComp[i], planeComp[i]);
    }
    break;
default:
    company.options.length = 1;
break;
}
}

function createOption(comp, text, value)
{
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = value;
opt.text = text;
comp.options.add(opt);
}

function getMessage()
{
var compVal =document.getElementById('company').value;
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'You selected ' + compVal;
}
```

**How the page works:**

Once the user selects the desired values, and fills up other information in the form (code not shown); he clicks on the submit button. Next page is the "Confirmation page" that asks user to either do the final "Submit" or "Edit". Edit button takes the user back to the previous page (window.history.back()), where he can change his selections or text values.

**The problem I am facing is**

When I go back to the form again. Everything I selected or wrote is retained except the value for second (dynamically generated, company names) drop-down list.

**Question:**

Is there a way I can make the 2nd DDl list to retain it's value when I traverse back to this page to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Save selected value to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example), and read it when you return.

You need to check your local storage first, and if it's empty -- use selected value.

```js
function saveForm() {
  localStorage.setItem('selectedMode', document.getElementById('car').value);
  localStorage.setItem('selectedCompany', document.getElementById('company').value);
}

function restoreForm() {
  document.getElementById('car').value = localStorage.getItem('selectedMode');
  document.getElementById('company').value = localStorage.getItem('selectedCompany');
}

function configureDropDownLists() {
  var carComp = ['Porsche', 'BMW', 'Merc', 'Audi', 'Hummer'];
  var planeComp = ['Boeing', 'BAC', 'BAE', 'GE'];
  var ModeVar;

  ModeVar = document.getElementById('car').value;
  
  switch (ModeVar) {
    case 'Car':
      company.options.length = 1;
      for (i = 0; i < carComp.length; i++) {
        createOption(company, carComp[i], carComp[i]);
      }
      break;
    case 'Plane':
      company.options.length = 1;
      for (i = 0; i < planeComp.length; i++) {
        createOption(company, planeComp[i], planeComp[i]);
      }
      break;
    default:
      company.options.length = 1;
      break;
  }
}

function createOption(comp, text, value) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = value;
  opt.text = text;
  comp.options.add(opt);
}

function getMessage() {
  var compVal = document.getElementById('company').value;
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'You selected ' + compVal;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span>Mode:</span>
  <select id='car' onchange='configureDropDownLists()'>
    <option value=''>Choose the Mode of Transport</option>
    <option value='Car'>Car</option>
    <option value='Plane'>Plane</option>
  </select>
</label>
<br/>

<label>
  <span>Choose the preferred company</span>
  <select id='company' onchange='getMessage()'>
    <option value=''>Choose the Company</option>
  </select>
</label>
<br/>

<p id='message' style='display:'></p>
```

Comment: Can you show a small snippet on how to use localStorage. I don't seem to make it work. I tried it...

Comment: @DeVeLoPeR i have add 2 new methods, one is for saving form, and second for restore. Run first, when you send form, and second, when you return to the page. I think it should work (didn't work in snippet because of same origin policy of "snippet").

Comment: Thanks for the example. It didn't work for me though. I saved the value on onsubmit form event by calling te saveForm(). and tried to reset the DD value onload event, by calling the restoreForm(). Doesn't seem to work for me... Also to add some more detail. All this HTML and JS code is written inside an FCGI program in C++. If that makes a difference..